# Time.zone.now & current machine time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

Seems Time.zonew.now depends on the machine current time. It's weird for me.

**application.rb**

```
 config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

I made the experiment.

**real current time time in CST time zone**

```
5:54 AM
```

**STEP 1) I have forced current machine time to 7:37pm**.

**system time**

```
drobazko@drobazko:~/www$ date
Mon Aug 17 19:37:35 EDT 2015
```

**rails c**

```
1.9.3-p484 :001 > Time.zone
 => (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada) 
1.9.3-p484 :002 > Time.zone.now
 => Mon, 17 Aug 2015 18:40:15 CDT -05:00
```

**STEP 2) I have forced current machine time to 3:17pm**.

**real current time time in CST**

```
5:54 AM
```

**system time**

```
drobazko@drobazko:~/www$ date
Mon Aug 17 15:17:09 EDT 2015
```

**rails c**

```
1.9.3-p484 :001 > Time.zone
 => (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada) 
1.9.3-p484 :002 > Time.zone.now
 => Mon, 17 Aug 2015 14:18:39 CDT -05:00
```

**Question:** why Time.zone.now doesn't give me real current CST time about 5am?

Comment: Guys, why was the question down-voted?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution here: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst

In Summer: CDT and Winter: CST. At the moment, we are in Summer :)

Comment: Did you see my question? This is not about daylight time.

Answer (score 1):

Time.now method returns system time, so Time.zone.now also returns system time but in the application's time zone.